# Decrypting a someone else's ciphertext

Tags: rsa

We have a scenario where two people A,B have the same modulus $N$ but different exponents $e_1, e_2$ respectively for RSA encryption. They have decryption exponents $d_1, d_2$ respectively.

Suppose for some message $m$, it is sent to B and A intercepts it, i.e. A has $c \equiv m^{e_2} \pmod N$. Assuming $e_1,e_2$ are coprime, how might A be able to obtain $m$?

My thoughts are that $\exists u,v \in \mathbb Z$ such that $ue_1 + ve_2 = 1 \Rightarrow re_2 = 1 - ue_1$

Then A may obtain $c_1 \equiv c^r \equiv m^{re_2} \equiv m^{1-ue_1} \pmod N$
which subsequently lets A compute $c_2 \equiv c_1 ^ {d_1} \equiv m^{d_1-ud_1e_1} \equiv m^{d_1 - u} \pmod N$

Now if $n = gcd(d_1-u, e_2),$ we may find $x,y \in \mathbb Z$ such that $x(d_1-u) + ye_2 = n$.

A then computes $c_3 \equiv c_2^x * c^y \equiv m^n \pmod N$

Now if $n=1$ then we are done. However, if $n>1$ then I am not sure what else to do. I would like to show something along the lines of either $n = 1$ always or that we may find $k\in \mathbb Z$ such that $nk \equiv 1 \pmod {\phi(N)}$ where $\phi$ is the Euler Totient Function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If they share the same modulus, either party should be able to infer the other party's private key from their public key just given their own key-pair...

Comment: @SEJPM Why would that be the case? The private key is such that the product is 1 modulo $\phi(N)$ but knowing N does not easily give us $\phi(N)$, so how might we be able to find $d_2$?

Comment: @user366818: we don't need to know $\phi(N)$ (or $\text{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$), it suffices to know $k\phi(N)$, for any $k > 0$.

Comment: @poncho So knowing one pair of keys $(e_1,d_1)$  we know that $e_1d_1 - 1 = k\phi(N)$ for some $k>0$. Then given a known $e_2$ we know that if $e_2d_2 \equiv 1 \pmod{\phi(N)}$ then $e_2d_2 \equiv 1 + l\phi(N) \pmod{k\phi(N)}$ for some $0<l<k$. I still don't really see how this let's us calculate $d_2$ without trying what might be a large number of values

Comment: Actually, it's $\lambda(N) = \text{lcm}(p-1, q-1)$, not $\phi(N)$.  That aside, the relation you need is $e_2d_2 \equiv 1 \pmod{k \lambda(N})$, where $k \lambda(N) = e_1d_1 - 1$; you don't need to search for $l$.  The only nonobvious point is what you should do if $e_2$ and $e_1d_1 - 1$ are not coprime; however it turns out that's not hard either

Comment: @user366818: the observation that you may have missed is that if $e_2d_2 \equiv 1 \pmod{k\lambda(N)}$, then $e_2d_2 \equiv 1 \pmod{\lambda(N)}$.  Now, this $d_2$ is likely not the minimal $d_2$ value, however it'll work to recover $m$ and that's all we care about

Comment: Also if you don't like this approach, you can always factor $n$ given $e,d$...

Comment: @SEJPM: well, yes, that is the obvious solution...

Comment: @poncho Doesn't that require that $gcd(e_2,k) = 1$? Otherwise how could we guarantee that a $d_2$ such that $e_2d_2 \equiv 1 \pmod {k\phi(N)}$ exists?

Comment: @user366818: that's the nonobvious part; however there is a solution...

Comment: @poncho after testing a few cases it appears to be the case that such a $k$ arising from $e_1d_1 - 1 = k\phi(N)$ is a factor of $\phi(N)$. Could you possibly confirm if this is the case?

Comment: @user366818: not in general; I suspect you're trying small $e$'s; that yields small $k$ values, and $\phi(N)$ has small factors.  For a counterexample, consider $N = 19 \times 23$, $e = 25$, $d = 301$.

Comment: Use "common modulus" in the search box to find six dupes.